# Is the specification for Power Query (M Query) open source?

Tags: open-source, powerquery

I was searching the web for examples of other implementations of M query, but didn't find any. So I concluded that Power Query is Microsoft's proprietary IP. I am asking this question because it would be tempting to develop a data service which is capable of executing M Query scripts.
If anybody has concrete information what the licensing status of M query is, I would greatly appreciate your feedback.

Regards
B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's implementation is not open source.
The language specification is [publicly available](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt807488.aspx), however.
The API for the standard library is also [publicly listed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt779182.aspx).